# Why can't exclude files with exclude argument in ctags command?

Tags: vim, ctags

I want to create tag file for C and C++, exclude all files in `/usr/include/python2.7`, all files in `/usr/include/*` instead of `/usr/include/python2.7` were created tag.

```
ctags -R -I __THROW -I __attribute_pure__ -I __nonnull -I __attribute__ \
    --file-scope=yes --langmap=c:+.h --languages=c,c++ --links=yes --c-kinds=+p \
    --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q  \
    -f .vim/tags/c.tag /usr/include/*  --exclude="/usr/include/python2.7"
```

It is no use to write it as

```
ctags -R -I __THROW -I __attribute_pure__ -I __nonnull -I __attribute__ \
    --file-scope=yes --langmap=c:+.h --languages=c,c++ --links=yes --c-kinds=+p \
    --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q  \
    -f .vim/tags/c.tag /usr/include/*  --exclude=/usr/include/python2.7/*
```

Why still many contents come form  /usr/include/python2.7 ?

```
grep  "python*"  /home/debian8/.vim/tags/c.tag
ysize   /usr/include/python2.7/Imaging.h    /^    int xsize, ysize, xoff, yoff;$/;" m   struct:ImagingCodecStateInstance    access:public
ysize   /usr/include/python2.7/Imaging.h    /^    int ysize;$/;"    m   struct:ImagingMemoryInstance    access:public
ystep   /usr/include/python2.7/Imaging.h    /^    int ystep;$/;"    m   struct:ImagingCodecStateInstance    access:public
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add more options after your target directory. That won't work.

This should work:

```
ctags -R -I __THROW -I __attribute_pure__ -I __nonnull -I __attribute__ \
    --file-scope=yes --langmap=c:+.h --languages=c,c++ --links=yes --c-kinds=+p \
    --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q  \
    -f .vim/tags/c.tag --exclude=python2.7 /usr/include
```

It is the same command you used with three differences:

1. Specifies `--exclude` option *before* the target directory to index.
2. Specifies the target directory (`/usr/include`) without a wildcard, as ctags already knows to look at everything inside.
3. Only has to exclude `python2.7` because only that directory name is needed. If it sees that directory name, it will not go in there and index anything. Full path is not required here.